# How to assign a value to a checkbox and use it in a formula?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm very new to all this programming and c# windows application, so go easy on me.

Basically I have 13 checkboxes which I want to assign values to, so when the checkboxes are checked those value goes into a formula:

```
consumption = energy * 15 / 1000
```

The "energy" is representing the checkboxes. I want all checked checkBoxes values to go there.

If its not possible to assign a value, what is the best way of doing it?

The only way I know is doing the following for each one:

```
if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
{
       energy += energy + 1200; 
}
```

I would like to do a `foreach` method but I don't know how to.

Comment: First I think you want `energy += 1200` or `energy = energy + 1200`, second, should the energy be lost `(energy -= 1200)` when the check box is unchecked?

Comment: No its only positive.. So if unchecked energy=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the values in the Tag property of the Checkbox control and you can do a foreach on Form.Controls check if it is an instance of CheckBox and perform your logic.

An example

```
    int energy = 0;
foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
{
    //you can have additional checks like name starts with to identify energy checkboxes
    if (control is CheckBox) 
    {
        energy = energy + Convert.ToInt32(control.Tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If yo have exactly 13 check box control, you can do that this way

First you have to set the  CheckedChanged event in every check box to the next event

```
private void All_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//Check if all the checkboxes are checked
        if(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked ... && checkbox13.Checked)
        {
//If they are checked calculate your value with your formula
            var energy = EvaluateEnergy();
        }
    }
```

Then the EvaluateEnergy can be something like this

```
private int EvaluateEnergy()
    {
        var energy = 0;
        if(checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            //Assign to every check box a energy value e.g 10
            energy += 10;
        }

        if(checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            //e.g 20
            energy += 20;
        }
        ......
        return energy + 1600;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming `energy` is a member in your class and you have a method to compute the consumption like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private double energy;
    ....
    public double consumption
    {
        get { return energy*15.0/1000; }
    }
```

(note the double and `15.0/1000` because `15/1000` is integer division and is 0)

You can then add an event for all your checkboxes that increments/decrements `energy` by 1200 whenever one is checked or unchecked:

```
private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    energy += ((CheckBox) sender).Checked ? 1200 : -1200;
}
```

(energy be equal to 0 when all checkboxes are unchecked)

you can add the event to each checkbox in the designer:

[image]